# Returning string is not successful

Tags: c#, string, winforms, function, return

I have a problem which may look easy but I can't solve it.
I have a function which returns a string and has two arguments:

```
public string MyFunc(string ID, string TargetID)   // ID is 9999999995 and TargetID is 9999999998
{
    return ID + TargetID;    // Gives me ID only(9999999995).
}
```

When I try to put text instead of the ID, it works, but not with a number. I've tried to use StringBuilder but I get the same result.

I use it like this:

```
MessageBox.Show(MyFunc(Settings.Default.ID, ComboBox1.Text));
```

Comment: Something is wrong with your testing - the function works as expected ([link](http://ideone.com/d87m6o)).

Comment: What are you expected as the result?

Comment: @SteveL I want to send a request to server which will connect two users by using their IDs.

Comment: It's magic, we need more code.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question. How are you calling this function (working case AND failing case), and what specific result are you expecting for your inputs? In C#, "adding" two strings concatenates them - dasblinkenlight's test shows what /I/ expect.

Comment: Debug through it and make sure the TargetID you are receiving is really 9999999998

Comment: absolute magic indeed !!

Comment: did you enter anything in ComboBox1 ?

Comment: @upcoming_coder ofcourse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everybody, but the problem was in receiving the string from netStream, That was my fault. When sending the string I haven't added the "$" char in the end and so the string maybe was so long or something...

Answer (score 2):

The function is working as intended.  Check that the incoming parameters `ID` and `TargetID` actually contain values and they are the values you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Check the values are not null to be safe and do a String.Concat(...)